# Details are getting repeated in my java program that uses database as back end

Tags: java, database

I'm desperately in need for help and i hope you can provide me some.
please see the following code. 
In the login page I'm storing the received seller id and password in receivesid and receivepass respectively. I have used these tables while checking to see if the passwords match with the corresponding username. 
When I login to the details page (PageD) i want to get the details of the seller with the corresponding id in receivesid. in the first try, i get everything exactly the way i want it. But the same details are shown everytime i log in even though the seller id is different. Also, the delete statements aren't working. As you can see, I've made them part of a comment.

Do you think you can help me? Please do reply. I appreciate any help i can get. 
Please forgive my bad english.

```
  // LOGIN

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
class SellerPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel cl1=new JLabel("SELLER ID");
    public JTextField ct1=new JTextField(20);
    JLabel cl2=new JLabel("PASSWORD");
    JPasswordField cp1=new JPasswordField(20);
    JButton cb1=new JButton("LOGIN");
    JButton cb2=new JButton("ARE YOU NEW?");
    String user="";
    String passw="";
               //Vector cbitems=new Vector();
               public SellerPage()
     {
    super("REAL ESTATE SYSTEM");
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(800,800);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    cl1.setBounds(80,300,150,20);
    ct1.setBounds(350,300,150,30);
    cl2.setBounds(80,350,150,20);
    cp1.setBounds(350,350,150,30);
    cb1.setBounds(300,500,150,30);
    cb2.setBounds(300,550,150,30);
                                Font f1=new Font(" ",Font.BOLD,20);
                               cl1.setFont(f1);
                                cl1.setForeground(Color.white);
                                Font f2=new Font(" ",Font.BOLD,20);
                                cl2 .setFont(f2);
                                 cl2.setForeground(Color.white);
                                 setContentPane(new JLabel (new ImageIcon("login.jpg")));
    add(cl1);
    add(ct1);
    add(cl2);
    add(cp1);
    add(cb1);
    add(cb2);
    cb1.addActionListener(this);
    cb2.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
{
    try
    {
         // DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
                      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
                      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Sajiendran-PC:1521:XE","system","password"); 
                      //   Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:am","system","password");                 
                             Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
        if(ae.getSource()==cb1)
        {

              String sqlup="select * from  password where seller_id='"+ct1.getText()+"'";
            PreparedStatement s=con.prepareStatement(sqlup);
             ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery();
                       if(rs.next())
                     {
            user=rs.getString(1);
            passw=rs.getString(2);
                      }      
                      rs.close();
                      s.close();
                      if(cp1.getText().equals(passw) )
                      {
               stmt.executeUpdate("insert into receivesid values('"+ct1.getText()+"')");
               stmt.executeUpdate("insert into receivepass values('"+cp1.getText()+"')");
                CustDetails cd1=new CustDetails();
                dispose();
                           }
                      else
                      {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid username or password!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                      }
        }
        else if(ae.getSource()==cb2)
        {
            SignUpPage sup1=new SignUpPage();
            dispose();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
   }
}
 class PageSeller
 {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    SellerPage sp=new SellerPage();
}
 }

      //DETAILS

           import javax.swing.*;
          import java.awt.event.*;
            import java.awt.*;
                import java.sql.*;
            import java.sql.ResultSet.*;
            import java.sql.PreparedStatement.*;
          class CustDetails extends JFrame implements ActionListener
         {
         JLabel dl1=new JLabel("NAME");
     JTextField dt1=new JTextField(30);
     JLabel dl2=new JLabel("SELLER ID");
    JTextField dt2=new JTextField(20);
    JLabel dl3=new JLabel("ADDRESS");
    JTextField dt3=new JTextField(100);
    JLabel dl4=new JLabel("PHONE NUMBER");
    JTextField dt4=new JTextField(20);
    JLabel dl5=new JLabel("EMAIL");
    JTextField dt5=new JTextField(30);
    JButton db1=new JButton("EDIT DETAILS");
    JButton db2=new JButton("ADS POSTED");
    JButton db3=new JButton("DELETE");
    JButton db4=new JButton("ADD NEW");
    JButton db5=new JButton("UPDATE");
               JButton db6=new JButton("LOGOUT");
   String s="";
   String a="";
   public  CustDetails()
   {
     super("WELCOME");
         setLayout(null);
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
           setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           dl1.setBounds(10,10,150,20);
             dt1.setBounds(170,10,200,20);
             dl2.setBounds(10,40,150,20);
             dt2.setBounds(170,40,200,20);
             dl3.setBounds(10,70,150,20);
             dt3.setBounds(170,70,200,100);
             dl4.setBounds(10,180,150,20);
             dt4.setBounds(170,180,200,20);
            dl5.setBounds(10,220,150,20);
             dt5.setBounds(170,220,200,20);
             db1.setBounds(20,260,150,20);
             db2.setBounds(20,300,150,20);
             db3.setBounds(200,260,150,20);
            db4.setBounds(200,290,150,20);
            db5.setBounds(200,320,150,20);
            db6.setBounds(380,10,150,20);
    load();
          add(dl1);
          add(dt1);
             add(dl2);
            add(dt2);
            add(dl3);
            add(dt3);
            add(dl4);
            add(dt4);
            add(dl5);
            add(dt5);
             add(db1);
            add(db2);
            add(db3);
             add(db4);
            add(db5);
            add(db6);
          db1.addActionListener(this);
          db2.addActionListener(this);
             db3.addActionListener(this);
            db4.addActionListener(this);
             db5.addActionListener(this);
            db6.addActionListener(this);

 }
public void load()
{
    try
    {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
                  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Sajiendran-PC:1521:XE","system","password"); 
                    Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
    String sql="select * from  receivesid";
    PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    s=rs.getString(1);
    rs.close(); 
    st.close();
    String sql1="select * from seller where seller_id='"+s+"'";
    PreparedStatement st1=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
    ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery();
    if(rs1.next())
    {
        dt1.setText(rs1.getString(2));
        dt2.setText(rs1.getString(1));
        dt3.setText(rs1.getString(3));
        dt5.setText(rs1.getString(4));
    }
    rs1.close();
    st1.close();
    String sql2="select * from phone where seller_id='"+s+"'";
    PreparedStatement st2=con.prepareStatement(sql2);
    ResultSet rs2=st2.executeQuery();
    if(rs2.next())
    {
        dt4.setText(rs2.getString(2));
    }
    rs2.close();
    st2.close();
    /*dt1.setEditable(false);
    dt2.setEditable(false);
    dt3.setEditable(false);
    dt4.setEditable(false);
    dt5.setEditable(false);*/

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }   
}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 {   
                         try
                          {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
                  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Sajiendran-PC:1521:XE","system","password"); 
                    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

                               if(ae.getSource()==db1)
    {
        EditPage ep1=new EditPage();
        dispose();
    }
    else if(ae.getSource()==db3)
    {
        CustDel cd1=new CustDel();
        dispose();

    }
    else if(ae.getSource()==db4)
    {
        NewAd na1=new NewAd();
        dispose();
    }
    else if(ae.getSource()==db5)
    {
        Adnumber adn1=new Adnumber();
        dispose();
    }
                 else if(ae.getSource()==db6)
                {
        /*String sd="delete from receivesid";
    String sd1="delete from receivepass";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sd);
    stmt.executeUpdate(sd1);*/
    dt1.setText(" ");
        dt2.setText(" ");
        dt3.setText(" ");
        dt5.setText(" ");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"LOGOUT SUCCESSFULL","SUCCESS",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    Proj p1=new Proj();
        dispose();
                }
                     }
                       catch(Exception e)
         {
         }   
 }
}
 class PageD
 {
    public static void main(String arg[])
   {
    CustDetails CD=new CustDetails();
   }
  }
```

Comment: I tried using the constructor, but it made it more complex. And I manually deleted everything from receivesid before logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tables, why not pass the logged in user through constructor to the `CustDetails` class?

```
public CustDetails(String s) {
    super("WELCOME");
    this.s = s;
    //Rest of code
}
```

So, after verifying password, you would've:

```
CustDetails cd1 = new CustDetails(ct1.getText());
```

In your current code, since you say you're not deleting data from `receivesid`, it keeps getting the first entry - thus resulting only in that same user. If you still prefer your tables method, then let us know what error you're facing when deleting? Why exactly you believe it isn't working?

Also, note that JPasswordField.getText() is deprecated for a reason. getPassword() is preferred.